# Javascript: How to get a list value based on ID?

Tags: list, javascript

I have a list with two columns: `Name` and `ID`. I have the `ID` value what is a unique field. I would like to get the `Name` value from the same row using javascript.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [SharePointPlus](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) JavaScript library. You can get row values like this using SharePointPlus:

```
$SP().list("My List").get({
  fields:"Title",
  where:'ID = 30'
}),function getData(row) {
  for (var i=row.length;i--;) console.log(row[i].getAttribute("Name"));
});
```

Comment: The code may have a ")" at the end, what is not the part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Name of the list item using the item ID. Here is the code below. The code below assumes that the internal name of the column that you wish to fetch is 'Name'  -

```
var itemId = 'yourItemID';   
var listName = 'yourListName';
var targetListItem;

function getName(itemId) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
  var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
  targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
  clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Name');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {   
   alert('Name is: ' + targetListItem.get_item('Name'));
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: May I ask you which item's ID is the "itemId"?

Comment: @Nefri "itemId" is the **ID** that you have as a unique field, as you mentioned in your question. You pass that ID in the function getName(ID), and get an alert of the **Name**

Comment: What if I have to get multiple column values? like name, description etc... how to do that?